# sSMTP rewritting From field in emails

Tags: freebsd, ssmtp

My problem is that whenever my server sends emails, the sender field gets overwritten.

`From:` should be: `Web Site Name <admin@mywebsite.com>`

But email is delivered to the address from:

`World Wide Web Owner <www@mywebsite.com>`

Or while sending the emails from the root in the SSH:

`Charlie & <root@mywebsite.com>`

My `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` configuration file content:

```
root=postmaster@mywebsite.com
mailhub=ssl0.ovh.net:465

rewriteDomain=mywebsite.com
hostname=mywebsite.com
realname = "Web Site Name"

AuthUser=postmaster%mywebsite.com
AuthPass=removed
UseTLS=YES
```

How can I instruct ssmtp not to change `From:` fields in emails? Or just define the `From:` anywhere?

When I add `FromLineOverride=YES` into the *ssmtp.conf* the server doesnt want to send emails anymore (email with set Form field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Should do the trick. Are you sure you are setting the From header correctly inside your mail sending code?